# I can't get the calculations to work

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a calculator that is suposed to figure the volume and the results come back as "0"

```
 JButton btnCalculateVlmn = new JButton("Calculate Hot Tub Volume");  
        btnCalculateVlmn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  
        {  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)  
            {  
                double width = 0, length = 0, depth = 0, volume = 0;  
                String lengthString, widthString, depthString;  
                lengthString = hotTubLengthText.getText();  
                widthString = hotTubWidthText.getText();  
                depthString = hotTubDepthText.getText();  
                try 
                {  
                    if (rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected())  
                    {  
                        volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length / 2.0, 2) * depth;  
                    }  
                    else 
                    {  
                        volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length * width, 2)  
                                * depth;  
                    }  
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.###");  
                    hotTubVolumeText.setText("" + formatter.format(volume));  
                }  
                catch (NumberFormatException e)  
                {  
                    labelTubStatus  
                            .setText("Fill in all fields");  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        btnCalculateVlmn.setBounds(20, 200, 180, 20); 
        hotTubs.add(btnCalculateVlmn);  
        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");  
        Exit.setBounds(220, 200, 80, 20);  
        Exit.addActionListener(this);  
        hotTubs.add(Exit);  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depth is declared as 0 and never overwritten... so the volume is always 0.
I guess you should do something like:

```
...
double width = 0, length = 0, depth = 0, volume = 0;  
String lengthString, widthString, depthString;  
lengthString = hotTubLengthText.getText();  
widthString = hotTubWidthText.getText();  
depthString = hotTubDepthText.getText();  
depth = Double.valueOf(depthString);
length = Double.valueOf(lengthString);
width = Double.valueOf(widthString);
....
```

Comment: And the same for length and width.

Comment: @Douglas: I'm not sure I'm doing this right. [code] double width, length, depth, volume; length = Double.valueOf(toString()); width = Double.valueOf(toString()); depth = Double.valueOf(toString()); String lengthString, widthString, depthString; lengthString = hotTubLengthText.getText(); widthString = hotTubWidthText.getText(); depthString = hotTubDepthText.getText(); [/code]

Comment: @Douglas: How do you format the code in a comment to look like you did above?  I don't think mine is coming through right.

Comment: that was probably me, I think you can only format answers, not comments.
I updated the example, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: @Douglas:  That worked for the calculations, but if I leave the field blank and click calculate an error should pop up.  Please see my exception above.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to convert the strings (`lengthString`, `widthString` and `depthString`) to doubles and assign them to your variables (`length`, `width` and `depth`).

Answer (score 1):

you have `depth = 0` and

```
anything * 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to convert your strings from the input fields to double.

you get 0 as result because you set length and width to 0

Answer (score 0):

In both branches of your main `if` condition your expressions ending `* depth`. However this `depth` variable seems to be set to 0 and not set to anything else. So volume will always be `0` since **whatever you multiply by 0 will be 0.**

Maybe you've wanted to use `depthString`. Something like this:

```
depth = Integer.parseInt(depthString);
if (rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected())  
{  
   volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length / 2.0, 2) * depth;  
}  
else 
{  
   volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length * width, 2)  * depth;  
}
```